# decimal and integer numbers that is less 91 with regex

Tags: regex

I have this regex
`/^(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?$/`

It allow all decimal and integer numbers.

What I need it to add all numbers that is less than 91.

How could I implement that ?

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integers or decimals **less than** 91 could be achieved like so:

```
^(?:0|[1-8]\d?|90?)(?:\.\d+)?$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nPaPHM/1).

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(?:` - Open 1st non-capture group:

  - `0|[1-8]\d?|90?` - Match zero **or** 1-8 and an optional digit **or** a nine with an optional zero.
  - `)` - Close 1st non-capture group.
- `(?:` - Open 2nd non-capture group:

  - `\.\d+` - A literal dot and 1+ digits.
  - `)?` - Close 2nd non-capture group and make it optional.
- `$` - End line anchor.

---

**Edit:** If you don't mind matching a double zero as per "00" or "00.0000" you could use:

```
^(?:\d0?|[1-8]\d?)(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Or, even less verbose, using a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!9[1-9])\d\d?(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
^(?:[0-9]|[0-8][0-9]|90)(?:\.\d+)?$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/xqLuv2/1)

***OR*** could be shorten as following too:

```
^(?:[0-8]?[0-9]|90)(?:\.\d+)?$
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^(?:                   ##Matching from starting of value and starting a non-capturing group here.
 [0-9]|[0-8][0-9]|90   ##Matching either 0 to 9 OR till 89 OR 9 here.
)                      ##Closing non-capturing group here.
(?:\.\d+)?$            ##In a non-capturing group matching dot followed by 1 or more digits keep it optional at the last of value.
```

---

---

***Bonus solution:*** Based on my assumption only, in case you want to match additional zeroes but still lesser than 91 then try following.

```
^(?:0+)?(?:[0-9]|[0-8][0-9]|90)(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
^(90|[0-8][0-9])$
```

Simply match `90` or `00` until `89`.

Comment: You may want to adjust the answer to allow for the integer part as per OP =)

Comment: My bad, this works just for the integer, but not the decimal.